# AWS bucket request settings location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-post

I've got an app that connects to AWS to send up potentially large video files into a bucket.

Problem is sometimes it's just bumming out.  I can't find where the settings are for the S3 bucket to set the "request limit", or "timeout" limit etc, like you would on IIS.

Anyone know where I can set/view these settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesn't have settings like that. S3 is *"infinitely scalable"* so you don't have to worry about things like that. Are you sure your issues aren't due to your network connection instead of S3?

If S3's response time isn't fast enough you might try enabling [Transfer Acceleration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html), or take it to the next level and place a CDN like [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of your S3 bucket.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I wasn't sure, but you've cleared up my confusion.